# wordpress ajax bad request 400

Tags: ajax

Where is my mistake?
html code

```
<div class="star-rating">
<span class="postid" post-id="52"></span>
<span class="score-bg"></span>
<div class="scores">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?>
        <div class="score" data-score="<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <span class="scoreAbsolute"></span>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(function () {
    $(".score").click(function () {
        var score = $(this).attr('data-score');
        var post = $('.postid').attr('post-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: post_score.ajaxscript,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'submit_score',
                'postid': post,
                'postScore': score,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert('nok');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

});

php code

```php
    add_action('wp_ajax_submit_score', 'submit_score');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_score', 'submit_score');
    
    function submit_score()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    //something
        }
        wp_die();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: @JacobPeattie last
add_action('wp_ajax_submit_score', 'submit_score');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_score', 'submit_score');

function submit_score()
{
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
//something
    }
    wp_die();
}

Comment: I asked _where_ is the code?

Comment: @JacobPeattie in my plugin

Comment: your `submit_score` function isn't doing anything, what are you expecting it to do? And can you add some context for what it's meant to do? What are you trying to implement and where are the code snippets you shared located? Use the `Edit` link under the tags to update your question so that it's easier to understand what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

Does you have localized your script correctly?
Please try the following method to enqueue your custom script and localize it.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts', 10 );
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/custom_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'ajaxscript',array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php' )));
}
```

Then you can call ajax url in custom_script.js as this way.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxscript.ajaxurl,
            method: 'POST',
            ....
        });
```

Comment: Yes I have. And it works well.

Comment: @Tara does this answer your question? If it solves your question consider marking it as the correct answer by clicking the tick button under the voting controls

Comment: @TomJNowell no!

Comment: that's unfortunate, but can you add some details then so that irfan can make improvements to their answer? Other users might also think that Irfan solved your problem and move on to other questions if you ignore it

Answer (score 0):

your onclick class is not in the HTML. you are calling  `$(".post-score").click` when in your HTML file the class name is `.score`

in your PHP code you want to handle the REQUEST. you dont have to check if the action is posted because wordpress is handling that for you by calling the correct function.

so your JS should be defined like this:

```
data: {
    'action': 'submit_score',
    postid: post,
    ticketScore: score,
},
```

and in your PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_submit_score', 'submit_score');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_score', 'submit_score');
    
function submit_score(){
    $safe_postID = intval( $_REQUEST['postid'] );
    if ( ! $safe_postID ) {
        $safe_postID = '';
    }
    
    $safe_ticketScore = intval( $_REQUEST['ticketScore'] );
    if ( ! $safe_ticketScore ) {
        $safe_ticketScore = '';
    }
    
    if($safe_postID && $safe_ticketScore ){
        // RUN YOUR CODE AND OUTPUT YOUR SUCCESS
        wp_send_json_success( array( 'postID' => $safe_postID, 'ticketScore' => $safe_ticketScore ) );
    }
    
    wp_send_json_error();
    wp_die();
}
```